# Pass html input value to knockout view

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, typescript

please help me with this issue that I have.

Embedded in CRM on Demand I have a view that needs to take values from CRM input fields to perform a search against CRM through web service and to show a view if duplicate records are found.

Here I have the code into some libraries against CRM {`crm.context.ts`}:

```
    /*
     * Context Helpers
     */

    declare var epmcrm: any;

    class context {


        private getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        config: { objects: { [key: string]: any } } = {
            objects: {
                "Homepage": {
                    name: "Homepage"
                },
                "Task": {
                    name: "Task",
                    idParam: "TaskDetailForm.Id",
                    screens: {
                        "/OnDemand/user/TaskDetail": "Detail",
                        "/OnDemand/user/TaskEdit": "Edit"
                    }
                },
                "Account": {
                    name: "Account",
                    idParam: "AccountDetailForm.Id",
                    screens: {
                        "/OnDemand/user/TaskDetail": "Detail",
                        "/OnDemand/user/TaskEdit": "Edit"
                    }
                },
                "User": {
                    name: "User",
                    idParam: "UserDetailForm.Id",
                    screens: {
                        "/OnDemand/user/UserDetail": "Detail",
                        "/OnDemand/user/UserEdit": "Edit"
                    }
                },
                "Opportunity": {
                    name: "Opportunity",
                    idParam: "OpportunityDetailForm.Id",
                    screens: {
                        "/OnDemand/user/OpportunityDetail": "Detail",
                        "/OnDemand/user/OpportunityEdit": "Edit"
                    }
                },
                "Contact": {
                    name: "Contact",
                    idParam: "ContactDetailForm.Id",
                    screens: {
                        "/OnDemand/user/ContactDetail": "Detail",
                        "/OnDemand/user/ContactEdit": "Edit",
                       // "/OnDemand/user/ContactInsert": "Create"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        private knownPaths: { [key: string]: any } = {
            "/OnDemand/user/Homepage": this.config.objects["Homepage"],
            "/OnDemand/user/TaskDetail": this.config.objects["Task"],
            "/OnDemand/user/TaskEdit": this.config.objects["Task"],
            "/OnDemand/user/AccountDetail": this.config.objects["Account"],
            "/OnDemand/user/AccountEdit": this.config.objects["Account"],
            "/OnDemand/user/ContactDetail": this.config.objects["Contact"],
            "/OnDemand/user/ContactEdit": this.config.objects["Contact"],
           // "/OnDemand/user/ContactInsert": this.config.objects["Contact"],
            "/OnDemand/user/UserDetail": this.config.objects["User"],
            "/OnDemand/user/UserEdit": this.config.objects["User"],
            "/OnDemand/user/OpportunityEdit": this.config.objects["Opportunity"]

            //"/OnDemand/user/CustomObj2": mapping to custom objects here is important!
        };

        webServiceUrl: string = null;
        screen: string = null;
        objectType: string = null;
        objectId: string = null;
        ssoToken: string = null;
        moduleRoot: string = null;
        rowId: string = null;
        commentsAction: string = null;
        status: string = null;
        //crm parameters to built the task link;
        account: string = null;
        accountId: string = null;
        contact: string = null;
        contactId: string = null;
        quote: string = null;
        quoteId: string = null;
        order: string = null;
        orderId: string = null;
        oppty: string = null;
        opptyId: string = null;
        lead: string = null;
        leadId: string = null;
        step: string = null;

        //crm contact

        lastName: string = null;
        firstName: string = null;
        email: string = null;

        constructor() {

            // pick out the info from the url
            this.webServiceUrl = "https://" + window.location.hostname + "/Services/Integration";
            // get the SSO token from the global variable defined in the web applet
            this.ssoToken = epmcrm.ssoToken;
            // get the module root from the global variable defined in the web applet
            this.moduleRoot = epmcrm.moduleRoot;
            this.rowId = epmcrm.rowId;
            this.commentsAction = epmcrm.commentsAction;
            this.status = epmcrm.status;
            this.step = epmcrm.step;

            //crm parameters to built the task link;
            this.account = epmcrm.account;
            this.accountId = epmcrm.accountId;
            this.contact = epmcrm.contact;
            this.contactId = epmcrm.contactId;
            this.quote = epmcrm.quote;
            this.quoteId = epmcrm.quoteId;
            this.order = epmcrm.order;
            this.orderId = epmcrm.orderId;
            this.oppty = epmcrm.oppty;
            this.opptyId = epmcrm.opptyId;
            this.lead = epmcrm.lead;
            this.leadId = epmcrm.leadId;


            //crm Contact
            $("#ContactEditForm\\.First\\ Name").on("change", function () {
                this.firstName = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.First Name")).value;
            });

            $("#ContactEditForm\\.Email\\ Address").on("change", function () {
                this.email = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.Email Address")).value;
            });

            $("#ContactEditForm\\.Last\\ Name").on("change", function () {
                this.lastName = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.Last Name")).value;
            });

            // attempt to discover contextual information
            var pathname = window.location.pathname;
            if (this.knownPaths[pathname]) {
                var obj = this.knownPaths[pathname];
                this.objectType = obj.name;
                if (obj.idParam) {
                    this.objectId = this.getParameterByName(obj.idParam);
                }
                if (obj.screens) {
                    this.screen = obj.screens[pathname];
                }
            }


        }

    }

    export = context;

In the view models I have what should give me the results into knockout observables which should than mirror CRM field and with this results I would perform a search and return or not some results:
`contactSearch.ts`

import ko = require("knockout");
import context = require("libs/crm.context");
import contacts = require("libs/crm.contacts");

$("#BTN_TB_ContactNewForm_Save").hide();
$("#BTN_TB_ContactNewForm_Save_idx_1").hide();
//$("#ContactEditForm\\.First\\ Name").on("change", assignFName);
//$("#ContactEditForm\\.Last\\ Name").on("change", assignLName);

//function assignFName() {
//    var firstName = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.First Name")).value;
//    alert(firstName);
//}
//function assignLName() {
//    var lastName = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.Last Name")).value;
//    alert(lastName);
//}

//function assignEmail() {
//    var Email = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.Email Address")).value
//    alert(Email);
//}


//var contactViewModel = function () {
//    var self = this;
//    self.validContacts = ko.observableArray([]);
//    self.addContact = function (validContact) {
//        self.validContacts.puch(validContact);
//        $.ajax({
//            data: ko.toJSON(this),
//            contentType: 'application/json',
//            success: function (result) {
//                validContact.fName(result.
//            }
//        });
//    }
//}

class contactSearch {
    private _context: context = new context();
    private _contacts: contacts = new contacts(this._context.webServiceUrl);
    private _firstName = this._context.firstName;
    private _lastName = this._context.lastName;
    private _email = this._context.email;


    vFName = ko.observable(this._firstName);    
    vLName = ko.observable(this._lastName);     
    vEmail = ko.observable(this._email);  

    //email = ko.computed({
    //    read: () => $("#ContactEditForm\\.Email\\ Address").on("change", function () {            

    //    })
    //})
    ////})
    //lName = ko.observable("");
    ////email = ko.computed(function () {
    ////    assignEmail();
    //})

    isSearching: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);
    searchValue = ko.computed({
        read: () => ("[ContactEmail]~=" + "'" + "" + "'" + " AND [ContactFirstName]~=" + "'" + this.vFName() + "'" + " AND [ContactLastName]~=" + "'" + this.vLName() + "'")
    });
    contactSearchResults: KnockoutObservableArray<IContact> = ko.observableArray([]);
    doValidation() {
        $("#ContactEditForm\\.Email\\ Address").on("change", function () {           
        })        
    }

    doContactSearch() {
        this.isSearching(true);
        this.contactSearchResults([]);        
        this._contacts
            .find(this.searchValue(), ["Id", "ContactFirstName", "ContactLastName", "ContactEmail", "AccountId", "AccountName"])
            .done((results: IContact[]) => {
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    this.contactSearchResults(results);
                    this.isSearching(false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#BTN_TB_ContactNewForm_Save").show();
                    $("#BTN_TB_ContactNewForm_Save_idx_1").show();
                    alert("# of matching results= " + results.length);
                }
            });
    }

    bindTR(element): void {
        /*
         * Replicate the CRMOD method of hover styles
         */
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.hover(
            () => {
                $element.attr("_savedBGColor", $element.css("background-color"));
                $element.css("background-color", "#d3dde6");
            },
            () => {
                $element.css("background-color", $element.attr("_savedBGColor"));
                $element.attr("_savedBGColor", "");
            }
            );
    }
    bindLink(element): void {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.click(
            () => {
                window["doNavigate"]('ContactDetail?ocTitle=' + encodeURIComponent(this.vLName()) + '&ContactDetailForm.Id=' + this.contactSearchResults["Id"] + '&OCTYPE=', true, this, null)
            },
            () => {
                $element.css("text-decoration", "underline");
            }
            );
    }
}

export = contactSearch;
```

David,

I have created the observables and I'm binding those here in the HTML view model, but the source for my data are those HTMLInputElement and I don't know how pass the values to the observables.

```
<p>Email <input data-bind="value: vEmail" />
    <span data-bind="text: vEmail"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: vFName"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: vLName"></span>
<p>Enter the search spec: <textarea data-bind="value: searchValue" /> 
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: validation, click: doContactSearch">Go</button></p>

<table class="list clist" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="m">
            <th class="m">
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Account Id</th>
            <th>Account</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="visible: isSearching">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="99" style="text-align:center;">Searching, please wait...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: contactSearchResults, afterRender: bindTR, click: bindLink">
        <tr>
            <td class="lrml">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ContactFirstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ContactLastName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: AccountId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: AccountName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also this file that create the dependency with CRM:

```
var epmcrm;
((epmcrm) => {

    if (!epmcrm["moduleRoot"])
        throw new Error("epmcrm global variable not configured");

    require.config({

        baseUrl: epmcrm.moduleRoot + "/scripts/app",

        paths: {

            // define the libs here
            // 1. External
            "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min",
            "jquery-ui.theme": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.theme.css",// recently added
            "knockout": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min",
            "text": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-text/2.0.10/text",
            "json2": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min",
            "knockout.mapping": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping", // added by daniel
            // 2. Internal
            "koExtensions": "../libs/knockout-extensions",
            "libs/crm.tasks": "../libs/crm.tasks",
            "libs/crm.accounts": "../libs/crm.accounts",
            "libs/crm.contacts": "../libs/crm.contacts",
            "libs/crm.users": "../libs/crm.users",
            "libs/crm.session": "../libs/crm.session",
            "libs/crm.context": "../libs/crm.context",
            "libs/crm.objects": "../libs/crm.objects",
            "libs/crm.utilities": "../libs/crm.utilities",
            "libs/crm.viewEngine": "../libs/crm.viewEngine",
            "libs/crm.viewmodelEngine": "../libs/crm.viewmodelEngine"
        },
        shim: {
            "knockout": {
                deps: ["json2"]
            }
        }

    });

    require(["knockout", "knockout.mapping", "koExtensions"],
        (ko: KnockoutStatic, komap: KnockoutMapping) => {
            ko.mapping = komap;
            ko.applyBindings({}, document.getElementById("QuoteWebAppletContainer"));
        });      

})(epmcrm || (epmcrm = {}));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but take note that you shouldn't be using change events or selecting values in knockout outside of custom bindings. You should instead create observables and then bind them to the view.

Comment: Hi David, I have created those observables and I bind those in the HTML view Model. Code is here:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm coming with the solution eventually, because I got what I need.

This were changed like this:

```
 $("#ContactEditForm\\.First\\ Name").on("change", () => {
            this.firstName((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.First Name")).value);
        });

        $("#ContactEditForm\\.Email\\ Address").on("change", () => {
            this.email((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.Email Address")).value);
        });

        $("#ContactEditForm\\.Last\\ Name").on("change", () => {
            this.lastName((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ContactEditForm.Last Name")).value);
        });
```

this three variables I changed to be observable properties:

```
 lastName: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");
    firstName: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");
    email: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");
```

And here I've made some other changes:

```
   vFName = this._context.firstName;   
    vLName = this._context.lastName;    
    vEmail = this._context.email;

    isSearching: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);
    searchValue = ko.computed(() => {
        return ("[ContactEmail]~=" + "'" + ko.unwrap(this._context.email) + "'" + " AND [ContactFirstName]~=" + "'" + ko.unwrap(this._context.firstName) + "'" + " AND [ContactLastName]~=" + "'" + ko.unwrap(this._context.lastName) + "'")
    });
```